# screenshots in android programmatically

Tags: android, screenshot

I want to take screenshot in my android activity through a program so that when a  user click on a button to take a screenshot, the screenshot shoudl be saved in SD card. I am adding the following code and facing some errors.In eclipse the package name in code is underlined with red line   TOSTRING(com.meri.meri_application).

```
    public class PartySalesandRecovery extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
     UserFunctions userFunction;
     DatabaseHandler db;
     String str;
     String moneyString2,moneyString3,moneyString4,moneyString5,moneyString6,moneyString7;
     String month,loginName,week;

     ImageView imageView;
      Bitmap bmp;

     int orientation;
     int total_sale_trg = 0;
     int total_sale_act = 0;
     int total_rec_trg = 0;
     int total_rec_act = 0;
     int total_per_sale = 0;
     int total_per_rec = 0;
     private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
         TableLayout tl;
         LayoutParams lp;
         Spinner quesWeek,quesMonth;
         Button btnShow,btnTakeScreen;
         JSONObject json,json_user;
          private View view;
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.partysalesandrecovery);
          view= findViewById(R.id.screenRoot);
          orientation = this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
          Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
          SimpleDateFormat month_date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMMMMMM");
          String month_name = month_date.format(cal.getTime());
          quesMonth = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.comboMonth);
          quesWeek = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.comboWeek);
          ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) quesMonth.getAdapter();
          int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(month_name);
          quesMonth.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
          tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayoutLocationSaleandRecovery);
          btnShow = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnShowReports);
          btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);
          btnTakeScreen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnTakeScreenShot);
          btnTakeScreen.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

///////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////

        public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

        try {
          ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
          File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
          f.createNewFile();
          FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
          fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
          fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
         }catch (IOException e) {
          Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        }

////////////////////////////////
         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if(v.getId()==R.id.btnTakeScreenShot)
        {
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);
        View from = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewRoot);
        Bitmap result = drawViewToBitmap(from, bitmap);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgViewpic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(result);

        saveBitmap(bitmap);

        try 
        {
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray()); 
        fo.close();
         } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), 7000).show();
          } 
           }

                code of XML

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/viewRoot" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
    <Spinner 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comboMonth"
        android:prompt="@string/month_prompt"
        android:entries="@array/question_months"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />
    <Spinner 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/comboWeek"
        android:entries="@array/question_weeks"
        android:prompt="@string/week_prompt"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Reports"
        android:id="@+id/btnShowReports"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Projects Sales and Recovery Status"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayoutLocationSaleandRecovery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:shrinkColumns="*"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >
    </TableLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/btnTakeScreenShot"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgViewpic"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: If you get to face the errors, why don't we?  Also, did you *mean* to enclose your code with single quotes?

Comment: http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/01/06/taking-a-screenshot-of-current-activity-in-android/ this link will help you out

Comment: Thanks allot MEENAL SHARMA       and JEREMY no i didn't close the code in single code in my program.. errors are in when I am adding the pakage name meri_application

Comment: have you tried the link i had mentioned..

Comment: @Meenal Sharma yes i viewed and want to know that it will save the pic in folder but i am not able to view it and dont know where it is saving its screenshots i found the folder but no image were their

Comment: please indent your code, readability sucks

Comment: have you tried my code..

Comment: @Meenal Sharma please tell me if i want to save the screenshot with mobile time and date.. what would be the code or please see my question and answer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26419942/save-name-for-screenshots-and-with-mobile-time-and-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace save bitmap method with this

```
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

just replcae your code with this code

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnTakeScreenShot) {
        Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot()
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        saveBitmap(bitmap);


    }
}


public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
}
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {

    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "test.jpg");
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: still cannot find image of screenshots

Comment: you have implemented the same code as in the link i have mentioned, because i have tried it and it is working, just done some changes in save bitmap method.

Comment: ya just send it i will check here at my side

Comment: what is your email address so that I can mail You

Comment: can you paste your code here..just edit your question and paste your code there..

Comment: oh thanks allot MEENAL SHARMA it is working now but overwriting the same image. please tell me how to ask user to set different name for different screenshots

Comment: just change the name text.jpg to user given name..show and alert dialog to user to enter name for image

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
// image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + ACCUWX.IMAGE_APPEND;   

// create bitmap screen capture
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(); // View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

OutputStream fout = null;
imageFile = new File(mPath);

try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

this answer is taken from this:
[How to programmatically take a screenshot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Explanation:
Output image path with image name:

```
String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + "ScreenShot.jpg";
```

Get the Screen Image of current view/display and create the bitmap from this:

```
Bitmap bitmap;
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(); // View v1 = mCurrentUrlMask.getRootView();
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

and finally save & compress the image:

```
try {
    fout = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fout);
    fout.flush();
    fout.close();

}
```

Comment: I have already viewed this but I am not able to understand it its little complex or may be I am not understanding it properly but somehow this is the problem

Comment: please, see my explanation... I think this will help you little bit.

Comment: please tell me that where the screenshots are going to be saved and where i would find my folder. and how would i know about that the screenshots of the screen are captured

Comment: check it into your device root directory. Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() with return device root directory (External SD Card).

Comment: still cannot find screenshots images

Comment: You should give the permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />